# Java Heap - Young Space changed after changing number of cores

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I've changed the number of cores on a vm that is running a java application (halved from 16 to 8).

The parameters for the heap size are unchanged but the young space is being reduced for some reason, which I cannot determine.

We run without setting a NewRatio, so the default should be the same unless the number of cores is taken into consideration when determining the size of the young space. I see little documentation about the default size of young space/new ratio that would indicate that the number of cores  is a determining factor, but as no other change has been made this appears to be the case.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible.  How the GC is tuned by default varies from JVM to JVM and from version to version which is why you might not get much documentation on the details of exactly how it works.

You can download the OpenJDK for the same JVM build you are using and read the source to find out what it does.

Answer (score 0):

HotSpot JVM have builtin heuristics rule to classify hardware as server or client class. These two classes have different defaults (some times very different).

Number or core and available memory are among parameters used by JVM to guess class of hardware.

There are two JVM options which could make this choice more deterministic.

- `-XX:+AlwaysActAsServerClassMachine`
- `-XX:+NeverActAsServerClassMachine`

Comment: We are using the HotSpot JVM. I haven't been able to find in documentation how the class of hardware is determined, and how this feeds the young space size determination.

Comment: This is not clearly documented. Oracle's JVM distribution is pretty close to OpenJDK, so only reliable way is to consult with OpenJDK code base.

Comment: Source code : http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/hotspot/share/runtime/os.cpp#l1665

Comment: *"Oracle's JVM distribution is pretty close to OpenJDK ..."*  - Correction: it is **identical** to OpenJDK.  At least for recent releases.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not worry about the size of the generations unless it causes severe performance issues.

Depending on the GC you use and the JVM options you set, Hotspot may dynamically adapt the size of the generation so that the GC cycles take less time (`-XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy`). It is one of the optimisations the JVM applies to make your application faster.

It is a good thing to wonder why the JVM resized the memory pool like this, but without any problem to solve, it is hard to go further ;-)

You should enable GC logs `-X:loggc:gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails`) and compare the 16-cores/8-cores memory consumption patterns to see if something is wrong. If your application is not slower and have no memory consumption problem, then it is fair to say these new memory pools are just a JVM optimisation.